# what is a good test environment to test JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find that I constantly want to test little snippets of JQuery and i would love a good method. Currently I go to the page that I am trying to test and open up firebug and enter the snippet and it should appear in the console. I was wondering if there is a better place or method that can help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That works. There's also [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which you might want to check out.

Answer (score 5):

There's also [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/), which let's you test out jQuery in a similar manner to jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the extension [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), which integrates with Firebug.